# JAVAFX 8 ComboBox and ObservableList

Tags: javafx, combobox, observablelist

I need a combobox populated through observablelist which contains specific data retrieved from DB. This is my source.

Model

```
public ObservableList<Bank> listBank = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public static class Bank {
            private final StringProperty id;
            private final StringProperty name;

            private Bank(
                    String id, 
                    String name
            ) {
            this.id = new SimpleStringProperty(id);
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);        
            }

            public StringProperty idProperty() { return id; }
            public StringProperty nameProperty() { return name; }        
        }
```

View

```
@FXML
private ComboBox comboBank<Bank>;

public final void getBankDataFields() {
        comboBank.setItems(model.listBank); 
    }

comboBank.setButtonCell(new ListCell<Bank>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Bank t, boolean bln) {
                    super.updateItem(t, bln);
                    if (t != null) {
                        setText(t.nameProperty().getValue().toUpperCase());
                    } else {
                        setText(null);
                    }
                }
            });

comboBank.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Bank>, ListCell<Bank>>() {
                @Override 
                public ListCell<Bank> call(ListView<Bank> p) {
                    return new ListCell<Bank>() { 
                        @Override
                        protected void updateItem(Bank t, boolean bln) {
                            super.updateItem(t, bln);
                            if(t != null){
                                setText(t.nomeProperty().getValue().toUpperCase());
                            } else {
                                setText(null);
                            }    

                        }                       
                    };
                }
            });

comboBank.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Bank> observable, Bank oldValue, Bank newValue) -> {
                setIdBank(newValue.idProperty().getValue());
            });
```

ComboBox is populated with NAME field and listener is used to get relative ID and pass it to a query for storing data on DB.

Ok, everything seems to work but i have two questions:

1. When user need to modify this record, i need to get the ID from DB and select the relative NAME in ComboBox. How can i do that?

   comboBank.setValue(????);
2. Is there a better way to achieve this goal? An ObservableMap may substitute the ObservableList?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should just use a `StringConverter` on your ComboBox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an easier way to what you are trying to achieve. You should use a `StringConverter` on the ComboBox to display the names for the Bank instances.

```
comboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<Bank>() {

    @Override
    public String toString(Bank object) {
       return object.nameProperty().get();
    }

    @Override
    public Bank fromString(String string) {
       // Somehow pass id and return bank instance
       // If not important, just return null
       return null;
    }
});
```

To get selected value i.e. instance of the selected bank, just use :

```
comboBox.getValue();
```

**MCVE**

```
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        ComboBox<Bank> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        ObservableList<Bank> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Bank("1", "A"), new Bank("2", "B"),
                new Bank("3", "C"), new Bank("4", "D"));
        comboBox.setItems(items);
        StringConverter<Bank> converter = new StringConverter<Bank>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Bank bank) {
                return bank.nameProperty().get();
            }

            @Override
            public Bank fromString(String id) {
                return items.stream()
                        .filter(item -> item.idProperty().get().equals(id))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
            }
        };
        comboBox.setConverter(converter);
        // Print the name of the Bank that is selected
        comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((o, ol, nw) -> {
            System.out.println(comboBox.getValue().nameProperty().get());
        });
        // Wait for 3 seconds and select the item with id = 2
        PauseTransition pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
        pauseTransition.setOnFinished(event -> comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(converter.fromString("2")));
        pauseTransition.play();
        VBox root = new VBox(comboBox);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Itachi but i don't know how to use it. What i need at first is to select programmatically an item of combobox (which displays names) starting from the relative ID stored in DB. Is your code useful to achieve this functionality?

Comment: @Andrea I have added a MCVE to the answer, hope it helps :)

Comment: Many thanks Itachi, with your contribute i've fixed the problem. Cheers and thanks thanks thanks again :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. It helps future users to find the solution to their problems faster.